# Every docker command Gives me Same ERROR

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers, docker-machine

My o/s is windows 7. Docker version is 1.12.0.
When i hit **docker images** command or **docker run hello-world** command,
it shows me below error:

Im typing these commands on Docker Quickstart terminal.

```
An error occurred trying to connect: Get 
https://192.168.99.100:2376/v1.24/images/json : Service unavailable.
```

What's the meaning of this? how to resolve it?

Comment: Please ensure your VM is actually running with IP address `192.168.99.100`. Sometimes with Docker Toolbox, IP address changes to another one (ie: `192.168.99.101`)

Comment: `docker-machine ip default`

Comment: thanks. But it is running on 192.168.99.100